# Find a maximal $\delta$ neighborhood where the following function is bounded

Tags: calculus

Let $\;f(x) = e\cdot \ln(x) - x + 1$, $\qquad f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Find a maximal $\delta \gt 0$ such that $ \lvert f(x)\rvert \lt \frac{1}{2}$ for any $ x \in (1 - \delta, 1 + \delta)$. If a maximal $\delta$ does not exist, find any such $\delta$.

Not really sure where to begin on this one, I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Showing that such a $\delta$ exists is quite easy, but I'm not sure that you can give its precise value...

Comment: That's where I got to as well, since the fact that a $\delta$ like that exists follows directly from the continuity of $f$ for $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. I just can't explicitly find any such $\delta$, never mind a maximal one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{\delta > 0 : |f(x)| < 1/2 \text{ for } x\in (1-\delta, 1+\delta)\}$.

As $f$ is continuous and $f(1)=0$ we know that this set is non-empty. Moreover it is bounded as e.g. $f(e)=1$. Hence, there exists the supremum of $S$.

Now focus on an interval $(0.5, 1.5)$ over which $f$ is strictly increasing (what is easily seen by calculating its derivative).
Observe that $\sup S < 0.3$ as although $f(1.3) < 0.5$ we have $f(0.7) < -0.5$.

Using continuity and monotonicity of $f$ to find $\sup S$ we need to solve the equation  $$f(x)=-0.5,~x\in (0.7, 1)~~~~~(*)$$
(There is a unique solution in this interval).

You asked whether there is a "maximal $\delta$", i.e. if $\sup S\in S$. We know $\sup S = 1-u$, where $u$ is the solution of $(*)$ and we need to check the condition $|f(x)| < 1/2$ for $x\in (u, 2-u)$ – hence $\sup S\in S$ and this is the "maximal $\delta$" we want to find.

However [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e+log+x+-+x+%2B+1+%3D+-0.5) can't provide a nice closed-form expression for this. It gives $x \approx 0.76233$, so $\sup S \in(0.2376, 0.2377)$. (Using similar method you can get more decimal places if necessary).